# Why $(y-\overline y)^t[f(x)-f(\overline x)]\ge-\Vert y-\overline y\Vert\Vert f(x)-f(\overline x)\Vert$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, inequality, continuity, proof-explanation

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^{m+l}$ be continuous and $\overline y\in\mathbb R^{m+l}$.

Why $0\ge (y-\overline y)^t[f(x)-f(\overline x)]\ge-\Vert y-\overline y\Vert\Vert f(x)-f(\overline x)\Vert$ ?

What relation exists between the transpose of a vector and the norm with minus sign?

Thank you.

---

Edit: sorry I forgot the 0 at the beginning of the inequality.

Comment: $\frac{v\cdot w}{|v||w|}\geq -1$

Comment: There is no more condition ?

Comment: @HKLee well this is a small part of a proof, but I think what I wrote it's all that one needs to prove it. Isn't it? Btw why it's true what you wrote $\frac{v\cdot w}{|v||w|}\geq -1?$

Comment: I think that for left inequality, we need more condition. And right inequality is followed from the fact that inner product of two unit vectors is greater than $-1$

Comment: $v^T w=v\cdot w$, and $\| v\|^2=v\cdot v$

Comment: @HKLee ah yes of course, my question is just for the second inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have claim that $$ v\cdot w\geq -|v||w| $$

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ f(v)=|v|$.

For $|v|=R,\ |w|=r$, then $|f(v)-f(w)|=|R-r|$. Clearly, $$ |v-w|\geq |R-r|$$

Hence $$ ||v|-|w||^2\leq |v-w|^2 $$

Hence $$|v||w|\geq v\cdot w $$